# Elasticsearch: piping or passing result of aggregations for further aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, filtering, aggregation, piping, elasticsearch-5

I am trying to get average of grouped minimum values of a field. [image: The current working query]

In the image, I am getting two buckets with min_time property in them.  I need to get average of this min_time. So, the final result should have only one bucket with average of min_time. I think, it can be achieved through piping but not quite getting it.

Comment: please consider posting json result instead of images to highlight your query/results. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for pipeline aggregations which is a feature in version 2.0 and later

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline.html